# Android - Phone Selector(HintRequest) is not giving Phone Number suggestions in all devices

Tags: android, android-intent, google-oauth, credentials, google-client

I am facing issue in `Hint Request Number suggestion dialogue` which appears on screen and quickly  disappears with weird animation.

This dialogue is working fine on some phones, but not working on all devices below is the code snippet.

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .enableAutoManage(getActivity(), this)
                .addApi(Auth.CREDENTIALS_API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        HintRequest hintRequest = new HintRequest.Builder()
                .setHintPickerConfig(new CredentialPickerConfig.Builder()
                        .setShowCancelButton(true)
                        .build())
                .setPhoneNumberIdentifierSupported(true)
                .build();

        PendingIntent intent =
                Auth.CredentialsApi.getHintPickerIntent(mGoogleApiClient, hintRequest);
        try {
            startIntentSenderForResult(intent.getIntentSender(), RESOLVE_HINT, null, 0, 0, 0, new Bundle());
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            Log.e("Login", "Could not start hint picker Intent", e);
        }
```

Comment: which phones are showing and which phones are not showing?

Comment: what error code it is returning?

Answer (score 2):

use below code to request phone numbers

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:17.3.0'
```

```
    private static final int CREDENTIAL_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;
```

```
    private void requestHint() throws IntentSender.SendIntentException {
        HintRequest hintRequest = new HintRequest.Builder()
                .setPhoneNumberIdentifierSupported(true)
                .build();
        PendingIntent intent = Credentials.getClient(this).getHintPickerIntent(hintRequest);
        startIntentSenderForResult(intent.getIntentSender(), CREDENTIAL_PICKER_REQUEST, null, 0, 0, 0);

    }
```

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == CREDENTIAL_PICKER_REQUEST) {// Obtain the phone number from the result
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Credential credential = data.getParcelableExtra(Credential.EXTRA_KEY);
                //credential.getId();  <-- will need to process phone number string
                Toast.makeText(this, "credentials\n" + Objects.requireNonNull(credential).getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Sometimes, hintRequest might show old numbers which was used.